# How do I implement a BroadcastReceiver in a Service Class in Android?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I need to implement BroadcastReceiver in a Service class I have created:

```java
public class MyService extends Service
```

In this class I have to implement a simulation of download by using a Thread - Sleep when the user presses the button in the `MyActivity` class which implements `sendBroadcast()`. I cannot extend the Service class to `BroadcastReceiver` as it is already extends to `Service`. Can anyone help me to figure it out how to implement this mechanism?

Comment: when you press the button, start the service with the button, and in your service register the broadcast reciever and sendbroadcast when the service starts, put another class that extends broadcastreciever in with the class that extends service

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have the BroadcastReceiver as a top-level class or as an inner class in your service. And get a reference of the receiver in your service. Like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    // use this as an inner class like here or as a top-level class
    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do something
        }

        // constructor
        public MyReceiver(){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
         // get an instance of the receiver in your service
         IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
         filter.addAction("action");
         filter.addAction("anotherAction");
         mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
         registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this broadcast receiver need to be added to the manifest also? With intent filters?

Comment: @rmmcnulty9 No, because the receiver gets registered at runtime in the onCreate() of the Service.

Comment: I am also having same situation, I want to run a service which runs in background infinitely, whenever we receive a sms it will shows a toast. For this i have created a class which extends Service. Which option would be the better, should i create a LocalBroadcastManager within service class or Standalone Broadcastreceiver for standalone broadcastreceiver it has to be register in manifestfile then how my service and broadcastreceiver communicates when i receive SMS?

Comment: Saved my day! ... and never forget to `unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);` in onPause or onDestroy

Comment: Wow, this is really a wonderful answer :) even after all these years

Comment: Any idea, why onReceive is not being called in my app?