# BroadcastReceiver within Service Can't Receive

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I register a `BroadcastReceiver` within `MyService`,

```
public class MyService extends Service {

final static String ACTION_ONE = "one";
final static String ACTION_TWO = "two";

 BroadcastReceiver receiver;
```

and a inner class

```
// use this as an inner class like here or as a top-level class
public class MyReceiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do something
        Log.d("tag", "received! MyReceiver2");
    }

    // constructor
    public MyReceiver2(){

    }
}
```

`onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
   receiver = new MyReceiver2();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(MyService.ACTION_ONE);
    filter.addAction(MyService.ACTION_TWO); 

    MyService.this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

And the code below is in `MainActivity` to send a broadcast:

```
    sendBroadcast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyService.class);
            intent.setAction(MyService.ACTION_TWO);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
}
});
```

I can't understand why `MyService`(**started, and is not yet destoryed**) can not receive broadcast.

If I change the `receiver` variable to a `MyReceiver` class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` and has already been proved to work,
`MyService` is still not receiving broadcast.

```
myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
```

Here is `MyReceiver`(it is proved that it works well):

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public MyReceiver(){
    Log.d("tag", "MyReceiver Constructor");
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("tag", "received");
}
}
```

============EDIT================

`manifest`
Both

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="one" />
            <action android:name="two" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```

do not work.

Comment: first of all: what do you need that receiver for?

Comment: `MyService` needs to receive broadcasts from notification action.  I started from letting `MainActivity` send broadcast.

Comment: a notification can start: 1) activity 2) broadcast 3) service, so use the option #3 directly

Comment: So, there is no chance that you need a service to listen to broadcast?  If chances are that you may need service to listen to broadcast, I want to solve this problem.

Comment: you are sending a broadcast from `onClick`, where is your notification? i dont see any...

Comment: Can't me start from sending a broadcast from MainActivity Button?  The problem is MyService can't receive any broadcast.  I send it from notification PendingIntent too, but not works.  I think it is MyService's problem, not a problem of how broadcast is sent.

Comment: do not use any broadcast, start your service directly

Comment: So there is not way a service can receive broadcast?  i dont think so. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861279/how-do-i-implement-a-broadcastreceiver-in-a-service-class-in-android)  Thank you, i may try another service, **BUT I REALLY WANT TO FIND OUT WHY MyService CANNOT RECEIVE BROADCAST**

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a manifest problem,

Please make sure you are declaring that receiver in the manifest!
for example:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.BackgroundTasksReceiver"/>
```

Comment: after i added `<receiver android:name=".MyService$MyReceiver2"/>`, it is still not working

Comment: why not creating a new class specifically for the broadcast receiver?

Comment: I wrote in my question, if I use `MyReceiver`, another `BroadcastReceiver` proved to work, `MyService` is still not receiving broadcast.

Comment: hmm, do you use that broadcast on the same process?

Comment: I edited my question and added some code, plz take a look on it.  And, I don't understand "use that broadcast on the same process", may you please explain it more?

Comment: Doesn't a service created on the main thread? MyActivity on the main thread sends broadcast.  They should be in the same process, aren't they?

Comment: you can find some useful info about process/threads here :
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread

Comment: have a look at this tutorial : http://101apps.co.za/articles/android-broadcast-receivers-a-tutorial.html